# Joomla Backend - Cannot login after switching to new host. "An error has occurred. 0 Cannot open file for writing log"

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator, login

I switched to a new Host after using a free hoster for months i finally got a good vHost.
But now i cannot login to my joomla backend anymore resulting in a strange error.
This happens whether i use my right or random credentials.
It just shows this:

[image]

I use Webmin for most settings.
I don't have a `.htaccess` set up.

here is my `configuration.php`: http://pastebin.com/ncbpDj4J

Do you need any other info?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!
I uploaded the site as root but the virtual server runs as an other user so it was just a ownership/permission thing (i initially changed the chmod of /logs/ and /tmp/ to 777 to find that it suddenly worked)